Android Jetpack Compose Canvas - How to zoom/magnify part of image using canvas?
I have two images stacked on top of each other: one is colored, and the other is grayscale. I want to implement a feature where, whenever the user drags on the image, a rectangular area above their touch pointer shows a zoomed or magnified version of the colored image in that area. This should function similarly to the Magnifier provided by Android.
@Composable
fun CardImageXRay(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    pairUrl: Pair<String, String>,
    saturationValue: Float, //0..1 visible = 0..1 else 0f
    isVisible: Boolean,
    imageWidthHeight: Pair<Int, Int>
) {

    val ctx = LocalContext.current

    val minValue = 0f
    val maxValue = 0.7f
    val mappedValue = minValue + (1f - saturationValue) * (maxValue - minValue)

    val boxWidth = ctx.resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels - 18 * 3f
    val boxHeight = 400.toPx(ctx)
    val imageAspectRatio = imageWidthHeight.first / imageWidthHeight.second.toFloat()
    val scaledWidth: Float
    val scaledHeight: Float

    if (imageAspectRatio > 1) {
        // Landscape image
        scaledWidth = boxWidth
        scaledHeight = boxWidth / imageAspectRatio
    } else {
        // Portrait image
        scaledHeight = boxHeight
        scaledWidth = boxHeight * imageAspectRatio
    }

    var isDragged by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var pointerOffset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset(0f, 0f)) }
    var convertedBitmap by remember { mutableStateOf<ImageBitmap?>(null) }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            convertedBitmap = getBitmap(ctx, pairUrl.first)?.asImageBitmap()
        }
    }

    val mdf = Modifier.size(width = scaledWidth.pxToDp(ctx).dp, height = scaledHeight.pxToDp(ctx).dp)

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 100.dp))

    Box(modifier = modifier.size(400.dp), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {

        AsyncImage( //colored image
            model = pairUrl.first,
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
            colorFilter = ColorFilter.colorMatrix(ColorMatrix().apply {
                setToSaturation(if (!isVisible) 1f else 0f)
            }),
            modifier = mdf
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectDragGestures(
                        onDragStart = {
                            isDragged = true
                            Timber.d("Dragged Start $isDragged")
                        },
                        onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                            change.consume()
                            change.position.apply {
                                pointerOffset = Offset(
                                    x.coerceIn(0f, imageWidthHeight.first.toFloat()),
                                    y.coerceIn(0f, imageWidthHeight.second.toFloat())
                                )
                            }
                            Timber.d("Dragged Pointer $pointerOffset")
                        },
                        onDragEnd = {
                            isDragged = false
                            Timber.d("Dragged End $isDragged")
                        },
                    )
                }
                .onSizeChanged {
                    pointerOffset = Offset(it.width / 2f, it.height / 2f)
                },
        )

        if(isVisible){

            AsyncImage( // GreyScale Image
                model = pairUrl.first,
                contentDescription = null,
                colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(black),
                alpha = mappedValue,
                modifier = mdf,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
            )
        }
    }

    convertedBitmap?.let {
        if (isDragged) { 
            DrawMagnifier( //Magnifier 
                pointerOffset = { pointerOffset },
                imageBitmap = it,
                imageWidth = scaledWidth,
                imageHeight = scaledHeight,
                zoom = 1f
            )
        }
    }
}

Here is the magnifier which I have created:
here problem is image is not drawing properly some image getting smaller some bigger and not aligned properly.

@Composable
fun DrawMagnifier(
    pointerOffset: () -> Offset,
    imageBitmap: ImageBitmap,
    imageWidth: Float,
    imageHeight: Float,
    magnifierSize: DpSize = DpSize(150.dp, 75.dp),
    zoom: Float = 1f
) {

        val ctx = LocalContext.current
        val magnifierWidth = magnifierSize.width.toPx(ctx)
        val magnifierHeight = magnifierSize.height.toPx(ctx)
        val zoomedWidth = magnifierWidth / zoom
        val zoomedHeight = magnifierHeight / zoom

        val srcRect = Rect(
            //Portion of image to be magnify
            left = (pointerOffset().x - zoomedWidth / 2).coerceIn(0f, imageWidth - zoomedWidth),
            top = (pointerOffset().y - zoomedHeight / 2).coerceIn(0f, imageHeight - zoomedHeight),
            right = (pointerOffset().x + zoomedWidth / 2).coerceIn(zoomedWidth, imageWidth),
            bottom = (pointerOffset().y + zoomedHeight / 2).coerceIn(zoomedHeight, imageHeight),
        )

       
        val dstRect = Rect(
            left = pointerOffset().x - (magnifierWidth / 2),
            top = pointerOffset().y - (magnifierHeight / 2),  
            right = pointerOffset().x + (magnifierWidth / 2),
            bottom = pointerOffset().y + (magnifierWidth / 2),
        )
  
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .offset {
                    IntOffset(
                        (pointerOffset().x - magnifierWidth / 2).toInt(),
                        (pointerOffset().y - magnifierHeight / 2).toInt()
                    )
                }
                .size(magnifierSize)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(50))
                .background(Color(0xFF464646))
        ) {

            drawImage(
                image = imageBitmap,
                srcOffset = IntOffset(srcRect.left.toInt(), srcRect.top.toInt()),
                srcSize = IntSize(srcRect.width.toInt(), srcRect.height.toInt()),
                dstOffset = IntOffset.Zero,
                dstSize = IntSize(dstRect.width.toInt(), dstRect.height.toInt())
            )
      }
}


I noticed an interesting modifier - https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).magnifier(kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Float,androidx.compose.ui.unit.DpSize,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,kotlin.Boolean) Maybe that one can help somehow
